# 2D Platform AI Jump

Tags: 2d

I'm working on a platform game at the moment. I have a problem with AI jump movement.
Path is already found with complete walk and jump points.
However jump action is problematic.

on example image:
AI should perform a jump at the red points and land on the next green point.

Do you know perform these curved jumps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As huntsfromshadow said you can look at making a parabola for which the formula btw is

```
y = -x * x
```

You can also tweak the formula a bit with a few constants... best way to test this is using wolfram alpha [http://www.wolframalpha.com](http://www2.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%20=%20%280.7%20%2a%200.7%29%20-%28%28x%20-%200.7%29%20%2a%20%28x%20-%200.7%29%29%20where%20x%20from%200%20to%201)

But I'll suggest different solution. Add a simple "jump simulation" which will look more realistic. 
 - add velocity to your entity
 - in the moment of jump add large upwards impulse by modifying the velocity
 - each frame add downwards velocity which suppose to be gravity
 - each frame modify the position by adding velocity to it

Don't aim for the first green point accurately. Make the jump to feel right and if the creature overshoot some of the green points just make it walk towards the next one.

Comment: i draw a bezeir curve and move character on it with a fixed velocity. 
i would like to make a jump simulation, problem is
levels are randomly generated. there infinite number of jumps ai can perform.

Comment: This parabola calculator helps significantly with wrapping your head around how this could work http://www.mathopenref.com/quadraticexplorer.html

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking at algebra and map the movement as a parabola.

Try different modifiers to the basic parabola equation of y = x (or y = -x as you are doing the  upside down parabola).